# How do I OnClick create iframes and update it's input's name so they are unique?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, chat

I am able to create the unique iframes upon click but I'm having trouble incrementing it's name attribute. The goal is to be able to have unique inputs so that i can set up the ability for one iframe input to chat with another.

```
index.html
<body>
    <p>+</p>
    <div></div>

scripts.js

$(function () {

    var id = 1;
    var name = 1;
    $('p').on('click', function() {

       var frame = $('<iframe />', {
            name: 'frame',
            id:   id,
            sandbox: 'allow-forms allow-top-navigation allow-scripts allow-modals allow-same-origin',
            src: 'iframe.html'
            });

       frame.find('input').attr('name', name); 
       $('div').append(frame);

        id++;  
        name++; 
    })
});

iframe.html


<input type="text" id="0" class="chatBoxes" value="type your message"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot modify controls in an iframe through your parent pages js if they are not part of the same domain.

If these are part of the same domain you can get your input element like so:

```
window.frames['myIFrame'].document.getElementById('myIFrameElemId')
```

myIframeElemId would be 0 in your example, and myIFrame would be frame I guess.

Comment: The iframe.html and the index.html are in the same directory on my machine locally.